# Axis labels with two different font sizes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is it possible to achieve the same result as in the X-axis below using just standard code from the **ggplot2** package (or any of the **tidyverse** packages)? I would like to have an axis label that consists of 2 different font sizes (e.g., 12pt and 8pt) without having to resort to loading additional packages (such as **ggtext** below).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext) # For element_markdown()

mtcars |> 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Miles/(US) gallon<br><span style = 'font-size:8pt'>[Min = 10.4, Max = 33.9]</span>") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `ggtext`?

Comment: Because I find it tedious to always having to add an additional `+ theme(...)` line, and I want to reduce the number of packages to load. This especially becomes an issue when I am producing *a lot* of figures for a project.

Comment: I found a way to do it buried in one of the answers to the question that you link to above. It's not the accepted answer, though, so I am posting this here again so people can find it quickly. Feel free to mark either question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Rather than posting a question and answer again, just upvote the answer at the other post that you think was better than the accepted one. There are only 3 answers there, so it shouldn't require that much digging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one neat solution using base R functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(atop("Miles/(US) gallon", atop("[Min = 10.4, Max = 33.9]"))))
```

[image]